# titanium sdk - [TiUtils isIOS9OrGreater]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1006f7610

Tags: xcode, crash, appcelerator-titanium

```
sdk 3.5.1.GA
Xcode
  6.4 (build 6E35b) - Xcode default
    Install Location          = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    iOS SDKs                  = 8.4
    iOS Simulators            = 8.4
    Supported by TiSDK 3.5.1.GA = yes
```

UPDATE: The app crashes when requiring the `tiTouchIdHandler.js` module at this code `tiTouchIdHandler = require('tiTouchIdHandler');` Any ideas why a `require()` would fail? It was suggested that my config was calling the wrong module as indicated by the `[TiUtils isIOS9OrGreater]` message. I renamed the file, reran the app, and received `[ERROR] Script Error Couldn't find module: tiTouchIdHandler for architecture: x86_64`. So, it's pointing to the correct module, as far as I can tell.

Yesterday, I ran the xcode Instruments memory leak test on my code without apparent issue. First and only time I've done so. Today, when trying to build, I receive this error at app startup: `[TiUtils isIOS9OrGreater]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1006f7610`. I thought it was the code, so I pulled a fresh copy from the repo, cleaned the project and ran it. Same thing. I then tried running in genymotion -- android version works fine.

I had both xcode 6 and 7 installed, so I uninstalled both, reinstalled 6, rebooted the machine, and then tried to run the app with this CLI

```
ti build --platform "ios" --target "simulator" --ios-version "8.4" --sim-version "8.4" --device-family "universal" --device-id "FF64FA87-57D3-46AE-A57F-92AA69585D0C" --sdk "3.5.1.GA"
```

Same result. I also tried running a sample generic app. The sample app ran correctly. The other developers can compile and run the ios version of the app without problems. It's just my Xcode installation.

Now I'm not certain that Instruments had anything to do with my problem. I also don't know why reinstalling the tools didn't work. I'm not certain if xcode stashes files somewhere or puts stuff in the keychain. What I do know is that I cannot build this particular app in my particular installation of Xcode. It makes no sense whatsoever. I'd appreciate any troubleshooting tips you can provide. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved the problem. Although, unfortunately, I don't know what the root cause was. My colleague sent me his sdk folder. I dropped it into place `~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA` - after uninstalling/reinstalling the entire toolchain - and the app builds again. Some unknown thing corrupted the `ti.touchid` file. Blowing it away and starting fresh was the only thing I found to fix it. Hope this answer saves someone else the 8 work hours I lost trying to resolve it.